# Oracle 12c R2 and jdk 6 compatibility

Tags: oracle12c

is oracle 12cR2 compatible with jdk6.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_01

Answer (score 0):

ojdbc8.jar from 12.2.0.1 works only with JDK8. However, other versions 12.1.0.1 (ojdbc6.jar) and 12.1.0.2 (ojdbc6.jar) JDBC drivers can be used with JDK6.

Refer to this [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03_1) for more details.